# pytest capture logging from function

Tags: python, logging, pytest, python-logging

For some reason I am unable to obtain the logs genereated in a tested function when using pytest. I've had a read around for all the usual solutions but am stumped, feel like am missing something obvious. Any advice would be much appreciated:

minimum reproducable example:

```
import logging

def function_to_test():
    message = "log me"

    logger = logging.getLogger("my-logger")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.propagate = True

    logger.info(message)


class Test():

    def test_function(self, caplog):
        with caplog.at_level(logging.INFO, logger="my-logger"):
            function_to_test()

        assert caplog.text != ""
```

Comment: Your code runs correctly for me without modifications. Can you tell us what version of Python (and pytest) you're using and on which platform you're running?

Comment: thanks for checking this, very interesting. I am windows 10, conda environment python 3.9.13, pytest 7.2.0. I will try some downgrades / upgrades and get back

Comment: Thanks I didn't realise pytest was running all test.py files in the project when using `pytest . -k "test_name"` and in a different test function I had disabled logging. Of course this behaviour makes sense - how else would pytest know what to include / exclude. but complete oversight on my part *facepalm*. Thanks for your help!